# Cutting/drilling sole plate on load bearing wall

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, framing, load-bearing, sill-plate

I’m starting to remodel my bathroom. It’s the only one in the house and it’s very small. 5’x6’ so to help save room I bought a concealed tank toilet. I didn’t do my home work and thought the tank ran in the wall but the waste pipe still came through the subfloor. I was wrong and the waste pipe gets hidden in the wall as well as the tank. The ideal location for the toilet though is against a load bearing wall. Is it okay/up to code to put a 3” pipe through the sole plate of a load bearing wall? Could I just do extra Framing like a window/door header and king studs above and around the tank to help keep it safe and structurally sound? I’m open for any suggestions and guidance! Thank you!

Comment: Is it a load bearing wall?  Load bearing usually is supported under the floor with a beam or foundation.  Cutting sole plates on the floor usually not important.  Removing/cutting studs usually is important to fix the way you said.  Do you need to remove studs for the tank/toilet installation?  If it is a load bearing wall and you need to cut/remove studs, should have a structural engineer to check and plan the work.  It is more complicated than just slapping some wood in there and hoping it stays up.

Comment: So I do have a beam running underneath but I’ve been a little stumped because the load bearing wall runs through the middle of my home but once it gets to the bathroom it stops and that center wall is pushed back about 6” it’s not inline with the rest of the load bearing wall. I will not need need to remove any studs for installation.

Comment: Removing the studs on that does require an engineer.  6" is close enough.  At least the 6" should mean the waste pipe misses the beam.  To make sure a beam is usually three or four large 2x together(or steel).  A joist is a single 2x10(~).  A wall on(or going same direction) a joist usually not load  bearing.

Comment: Oops sorry had typo, will not** need to remove any studs. Tank will fit right in between existing studs. Definitely a beam underneath and yes thankfully I will have just enough clearance to miss it with the waste pipe.

Comment: That typo almost cost you.  With no studs/joists/beams to cut/move, cut the sole plate and have fun.

Comment: Awesome thank you so much for the help!